How to fix the issue of losing a keystroke when editing a tablecell in JavaFX when migrating from JavaFX 8 to 21?
Recently we have begun a migration from Java 8 - 21 and part of that is JavaFX. We have run into a significant issue with our editable tables (we have many controls with this issue). The functionality should be as follows - when the user tabs into a cell, then starts typing, the field should immediately start editing. This worked fine in Java FX8, but in 21 it's losing the first keystroke - I have tried several things to fix it, but none work consistently I am curious if anyone has solved this issue? I understand this issue resulted from changes to event flow in Java 11. This is a breaking change for my application and I am unable to migrate up until I find a solution.
Thanks for any suggestions.
public class EditableLongTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T,Long>{ 

private TextField textField; 
private final Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+"); 


private ChangeListener<? super Boolean> changeListener = (obs, ov, nv) -> { 
    if (!nv) { 
        if((intPattern.matcher(textField.getText()).matches())) { 
            commitEdit(Long.parseLong((textField.getText()))); 
        } 

    } 
}; 

@Override 
public void startEdit() { 
    if(editableProperty().get()){ 
        if (!isEmpty()) { 
            super.startEdit(); 
            createTextField(); 
            setText(null); 
            setGraphic(textField); 
            textField.requestFocus(); 
        } 
    } 
} 

@Override 
public void cancelEdit() { 
    super.cancelEdit(); 
    if(getItem()!=null && !StringUtility.isBlankOrNull(getItem().toString())) { 
    setText(getItem().toString()); 
    } else { 
        setText(""); 
    } 
    setGraphic(null); 
} 

@Override 
public void updateItem(Long item, boolean empty) { 
    super.updateItem(item, empty); 
    if (empty) { 
        setText(null); 
        setGraphic(null); 
    } else { 
        if (isEditing()) { 
            if (textField != null) { 
                textField.setText(item.toString()); 
                textField.selectAll(); 
            } 
            setText(null); 
            setGraphic(textField); 
        } else { 
            if(item != null && !StringUtility.isBlankOrNull(item.toString())) { 
                NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
                nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0); 
                nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0); 
                setText(nf.format(item)); 
            }else { 
                setText(""); 
            } 
            setGraphic(null); 
        } 
    } 
} 


private void createTextField() { 
    textField = new TextField(getString()); 
    textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new TextFieldNumberFilter()); 
    textField.setOnAction(evt -> { 
        Long item = null; 
        if(!StringUtility.isBlankOrNull(textField.getText())){ 
            item = Long.parseLong((textField.getText())); 
        } 
        commitEdit(item); 
    }); 
    textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2); 
    textField.focusedProperty().addListener(changeListener); 

    textField.setOnKeyPressed((ke) -> { 
        if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ESCAPE)) { 
            textField.focusedProperty().removeListener(changeListener); 
            cancelEdit(); 
        } 
        if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.TAB)) { 
            if(textField.getText() != null && !StringUtility.isBlankOrNull(textField.getText())) { 
                commitEdit(Long.parseLong(textField.getText())); 
            }else { 
                commitEdit(null); 
            } 
        } 
        if(ke.getCode().isLetterKey()){ 
            ke.consume(); 
        } 
    }); 
} 


@Override 
public void commitEdit(Long item) { 
    textField.focusedProperty().removeListener(changeListener); 
    if (isEditing()) { 
        super.commitEdit(item); 
    } else { 
        final TableView<T> table = getTableView(); 
        if (table != null) { 
            TablePosition<T, Long> position = new TablePosition<T, Long>(getTableView(), 
                    getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn()); 
            CellEditEvent<T, Long> editEvent = new CellEditEvent<T, Long>(table, position, 
                    TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item); 
            Event.fireEvent(getTableColumn(), editEvent); 
        } 
        updateItem(item, false); 
        if (table != null) { 
            table.edit(-1, null); 
        } 

    } 
} 

protected String getString() { 
    return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString(); 
} 

}

Probably (but not definitely) off topic: it's better to use a TextFormatter on the text field to veto non-numeric entry than to use an event filter for key typed events. Using a low-level event handler (such as for key events) has the potential to interact with the text field's internal event handling, and as such could break if the internal implementation changes. (Also, doesn't this fail if the user uses the mouse to paste text in?)

I also wonder if this is better implemented with cells "permanently in an editing state" (as in the table view documentation), so you just display text fields all the time. You could use CSS to make them look like labels when not in a focused cell if you wanted.

Here is a suggestion, which reduces (but doesn't quite eliminate) the amount of low-level event handling on the text field. This significantly reduces the extent to which your event handling might interact with the text field's and cell's internal event handling, so should reduce the possibility of breaking changes going forward. This is just a suggestion and not a complete solution, but it might be enough for you to move forward.
Two strategies are implemented here:

Use a TextFormatter (introduced in JavaFX 8u40) to implement the numeric text field. As well as being an API-supported way to filter typing in the text field, the formatter's value is committed either when an action is fired on the text field or when the text field loses focus, which gives a more natural way to fire changes on the underlying model.
Implement the cells as "always in editing mode"; i.e. always display a text field instead of using the text. This approach is hinted at briefly in the "Editing" section of the table view documentation. This feels like a more natural fit for the requirement ("when the user tabs into a cell, then starts typing, the field should immediately start editing"). This will of course change the look of the table, but I partially address this below.

Here is a cell implementation using this approach. I also changed this to lazily create the text field (instead of creating a new one every time it's needed) and used some more modern Java idioms
public class EditableLongEditingCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Long> {
    private TextField textField ;
    private Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("^-?\\d*$");

    private TextFormatter<Long> formatter;


    private TextField getTextField() {
        if (textField == null) {
            textField = new TextField();
            // allow only integer input:
            formatter = new TextFormatter<>(
                    new StringConverter<>() {
                        @Override
                        public String toString(Long value) {
                            return value.toString();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Long fromString(String s) {
                            return s.isBlank() ? 0 : Long.parseLong(s);
                        }
                    },
                    0L,
                    change -> {
                        if (intPattern.matcher(change.getControlNewText()).matches()) {
                            return change;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
            );
            textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
            
            // commit change when formatter's value changes:
            formatter.valueProperty().addListener((_, old, value) -> {
                if (getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getTableRow().getItem()) instanceof Property<Long> p) {
                    p.setValue(value);
                };
            });
            // revert text when "escape" is pressed:
            textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    textField.setText(formatter.getValueConverter().toString(formatter.getValue()));
                }
            });
        }
        return textField;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Long item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(getTextField());
            formatter.setValue(item);
        }
    }
}

To address the change in look, if you need, consider just styling the text field as a label when it's not focused. The following is just a prototype of this (it doesn't interact correctly with the selected row in the table, but that should be fixable).
For simplicity (so you don't have to replicate the styling of the text field in your own CSS), introduce an "unfocused" pseudoclass to the text field:
// in the cell implementation:
private final PseudoClass unfocused = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unfocused");

and then in the getTextField() method, when the text field is created, do
// update "unfocused" CSS psuedoclass:
textField.focusedProperty().subscribe(focused ->
    textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(unfocused, !focused)
);

Finally, add the following to a stylesheet. Note if you need to keep this local in your code you can actually just add the stylesheet to the cell:
.table-cell .text-field:unfocused {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-cursor: inherit;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

Here's a complete example demonstrating proof of concept:

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private static final String STYLE = """
            data:text/css,
            .table-cell .text-field:unfocused {
                -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
                -fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background;
                -fx-background-insets: 0;
                -fx-background-radius: 0;
                -fx-cursor: inherit;
                -fx-padding: 0;
            }
            """;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Item, String> itemCol = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        itemCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue().getName()));
        table.getColumns().add(itemCol);
        TableColumn<Item, Long> indexCol = new TableColumn<>("Index");
        indexCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().indexProperty().asObject());
        indexCol.setCellFactory(_ -> new EditableLongEditingCell<>());
        table.getColumns().add(indexCol);
        TableColumn<Item, Long> valueCol = new TableColumn<>("Value");
        valueCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().valueProperty().asObject());
        valueCol.setCellFactory(_ -> new EditableLongEditingCell<>());
        table.getColumns().add(valueCol);
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, i, rng.nextInt(-1000, 1000)));
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table));
        scene.getStylesheets().add(STYLE);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static class EditableLongEditingCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Long> {
        private TextField textField ;

        private TextFormatter<Long> formatter;
        private final PseudoClass unfocused = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unfocused");

        private TextField getTextField() {
            if (textField == null) {
                textField = new TextField();
                // allow only integer input:
                formatter = new LongTextFormatter();
                textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
                // update "unfocused" CSS psuedoclass:
                textField.focusedProperty().subscribe(focused ->
                        textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(unfocused, !focused)
                );
                // commit change when formatter's value changes:
                formatter.valueProperty().addListener((_, _, value) -> {
                    if (getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getTableRow().getItem()) instanceof Property<Long> p) {
                        p.setValue(value);
                    }
                });
                // revert value when "escape" is pressed:
                textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
                    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        textField.setText(formatter.getValueConverter().toString(formatter.getValue()));
                    }
                });
            }
            return textField;
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Long item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setGraphic(getTextField());
                formatter.setValue(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class LongTextFormatter extends TextFormatter<Long> {
        private static final Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile("^-?\\d*$");

        LongTextFormatter() {
            super(new LongStringConverter(), 0L, LongTextFormatter::processChange);
        }
        private static Change processChange(Change change) {
            // There is more you can do here as the API for Change is pretty rich
            // E.g. with some work you can make it toggle the sign if the user
            // presses "-" at any point in the text
            if (intPattern.matcher(change.getControlNewText()).matches()) {
                return change;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class LongStringConverter extends StringConverter<Long> {
        @Override
        public String toString(Long value) {
            return value.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Long fromString(String s) {
            return s.isBlank() ? 0 : Long.parseLong(s);
        }
    }

    private static class Item {
        private final String name ;

        private final LongProperty value = new SimpleLongProperty();
        private final LongProperty index = new SimpleLongProperty();

        public Item(String name, long index, long value) {
            this.name = name;
            setIndex(index);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public long getIndex() {
            return index.get();
        }

        public LongProperty indexProperty() {
            return index;
        }

        public void setIndex(long index) {
            this.index.set(index);
        }

        public long getValue() {
            return value.get();
        }

        public LongProperty valueProperty() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(long value) {
            this.value.set(value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}


Thanks - will give it a shot - trying without the styling for now - we used tab to navigate the table, so I will need to look into that flow since it's not landing in the field.
